# Laravel Eager Loading tickets from DB

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

So I have the following relationship in my Model:

### Events Model:

```
class Events extends Model
{
    use CrudTrait;
    use HasFactory;

    use Sluggable;


    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'url',
        'start',
        'end',
        'category',
        'level',
        'bookable',
        'additional_info',
        'repeats',
        'duration',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'id' => 'integer',
        'start' => 'datetime',
        'end' => 'datetime',
        'category' => 'string',
        'level' => 'integer',
        'boookable' => 'boolean',
        'repeats' => 'integer',
        'duration' => 'integer',
    ];

    public function tickets()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Tickets::class, 'event_id');

    }
}
```

the function `public function tickets()` above is what I am talking about.

### Tickets Model:

```
class Tickets extends Model
{
    use CrudTrait;
    use HasFactory;

    public $fillable = [
        'title',
        'price',
        'min',
        'max',
        'students',
        'event_id'
    ];

}
```

then I show the ticket pricings on the frontend in a blade:

```
@foreach($events as $event)
    <div
        class="group-hover:hidden">
        {{ $event->tickets->count() > 1 ? 'Starting at:' : '' }}
        @if ($event->tickets->min(fn($row) => $row->price) === '0.00')
            Free
        @else ($event->tickets->min(fn($row) => $row->price) !== 0)
            {{$event->tickets->min(fn($row) => $row->price)}} €
        @endif
    </div>
@endforeach
```

### Controller:

```
public function showEvents($course)
{
    // function for the /events/{$course} pages
    [$view, $id] = match ($course) {
        default => ['error', 'error'],
        // URL Request from ($course) then the set the $view and $id
        'loremimpsum' => ['pages.course.loremimpsum', '2'],
        'impsumlorem' => ['pages.course.impsumlorem', '3'],
        'loremlorem' => ['pages.course.loremlorem', '4'],
        'impsumimpsum' => ['pages.course.impsumimpsum', '5'],
        'looremloorem' => ['pages.course.looremloorem', '6'],
        'impsimps' => ['pages.course.impsimps', '7'],
        'loremloremlorem' => ['pages.course.loremloremlorem', '8'],
    };

    try {
        return view($view, [
            'events' => Events::query()
                ->orderBy('title')
                ->orderBy('start')
                ->where('category', $id)
                ->where('start', '>', now())
                ->get()

        ]);
    } catch (InvalidArgumentException) {
        return Redirect::route('all-events')->with('error', 'You were redirected! This event was not found.');
    }
}
```

### Route:

```
Route::get('/events/{course}', [EventsController::class, 'showEvents']);
```

first I check if there are more than two tickets on one event, then it will show  `Starting at`. Then I check if the price on the ticket is 0, if this is the case I set the text on the button to `Free`. After that I check if the price is not 0 and whow the real price from the DB.

### The question:

How would one Eager Load these tickets and are there further optimizations? There are several thousand tickets in the DB.

The [documentation from Laravel for Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) only show an example with `belongsTo` not with `hasMany`. And StackOverflow has no answers with hasMany and a `foreignKey`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Review

### Readability is good though model naming could be better

As someone who has used laravel for many years the code is simple to read. One critique would be that typically models are named in a singular fashion - e.g. `Event` instead of `Events`, even though the database table name may be named in a plural manner.

### Template likely has a flaw

There appears to be a mistake in the template:

> ```
> @else ($event->tickets->min(fn($row) => $row->price) !== 0)
> ```

Shouldn't that be an `elseif`?

## Question Response

> ## *How would one Eager Load these tickets and are there further optimizations? There are several thousand tickets in the DB.*

The section in the documentation above the Section [**Eager loading**](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) is [**Aggregating Related Models**](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#aggregating-related-models) discusses eager loading aggregates for the hasMany relations. The [**One to Many** section](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) sets up the `comments` relationship for the `Post` model:

> ```
> <?php
>  
> namespace App\Models;
>  
> use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
>  
> class Post extends Model
> {
>     /**
>      * Get the comments for the blog post.
>      */
>     public function comments()
>     {
>         return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
>     }
> }
> ```

<sup>[1](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)</sup>

The first section about aggregating models demonstrates getting the count of comments:

> #### [Counting Related Models](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models)
>
> Sometimes you may want to count the number of related models for a
> given relationship without actually loading the models. To accomplish
> this, you may use the `withCount` method. The `withCount` method will
> place a `{relation}_count` attribute on the resulting models:
>
> ```
> use App\Models\Post;
>  
> $posts = Post::withCount('comments')->get();
>  
> foreach ($posts as $post) {
>     echo $post->comments_count;
> }
> ```

<sup>[2](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#aggregating-related-models)</sup>

So to get the count of tickets the [`withCount()`](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/QueriesRelationships.html#method_withCount) method can be used. Also, the call to `query()` can be removed since methods like that as well as `Model::where()` and `Model::orderBy()` [return an instance of `\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#building-queries):

```
Events::withCount('tickets')
    ->orderBy('title')
    ->orderBy('start')
    ->where('category', $id)
    ->where('start', '>', now())
    ->get()
```

Then each `Event` model will have an attribute `tickets_count` that can be used to get the count of tickets instead of `$event->tickets->count()`.

The [**Other Aggregate Functions** section](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#other-aggregate-functions) mentions the `withMin` method.

> In addition to the `withCount` method, Eloquent provides `withMin`,
> `withMax`, `withAvg`, `withSum`, and `withExists` methods. These methods will
> place a `{relation}_{function}_{column}` attribute on your resulting
> models:
>
> ```
> use App\Models\Post;
>  
> $posts = Post::withSum('comments', 'votes')->get();
>  
> foreach ($posts as $post) {
>     echo $post->comments_sum_votes;
> }
> ```

So to get the minimum price of the tickets for each event a call to [`withMin()`](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/QueriesRelationships.html#method_withMin) can be added:

```
Events::withCount('tickets')
    ->withMin('tickets', 'price')
    ->orderBy('title')
    ->orderBy('start')
    ->where('category', $id)
    ->where('start', '>', now())
    ->get()
```

Then each `Event` model should have an attribute `tickets_min_price` that can be used instead of `$event->tickets->min(fn($row) => $row->price)`.

Thus instead of a query to get the events plus one query for each event, there is a single query like:

> ```
> select "events".*, 
>     (select count(*) from "tickets" where "events"."id"  = "tickets"."event_id") as "tickets_count", 
>     (select min("tickets"."price") from "tickets" where "events"."id" = "tickets"."event_id") as "tickets_min_price" 
> from "events" 
> where "category" = '7' and "start" > '2024-01-09 23:55:23' 
> order by "title" asc, "start" asc
> ```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for this explanation! The trick with the `tickets_min_price` and `tickets_count` is very smart. This did indeed fix the issue I had. :)